# Use mutate_each to divide a set of rows in R by 2

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this

```
Letter   Number1 Number2 Number3 Type
A           4      5        3      10
B           10     22       24     20
C           50     24       100    30
D           60     32       12     40
```

Where I would like to use mutate_each to divide number1, number2, and number3 by 2, and not do anything to Letter and type.
Is there an easy day to do this?

This is what I would want the final DF to look like

```
Letter   Number1 Number2 Number3 Type
A           2      2.5     1.5     10
B           5      11       12     20
C           25     12       50    30
D           30     16       6     40
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use base R: `df[,grepl('Number',names(df))] = df[,grepl('Number',names(df))]/2`

Answer (score 6):

We can select the 'Number' columns using `starts_with` or `matches` and divide those columns by 2.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_each(df1, funs(./2), starts_with('Number'))
#    Letter Number1 Number2 Number3 Type
#1      A       2     2.5     1.5   10
#2      B       5    11.0    12.0   20
#3      C      25    12.0    50.0   30
#4      D      30    16.0     6.0   40
```

As @Cotton.Rockwood suggested in the comments, in the newer versions of `dplyr` (`0.7.6`), we can use `mutate_at` (for changing a subset of columns) or `mutate_all` (to change all the columns)

```
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Number")), funs(./2))
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), get the column names that start with 'Number' ('nm1'), assign the 'nm1' with the new value ie. after dividing by '2'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
setDT(df1)
nm1 <- grep('^Number', names(df1), value=TRUE)
df1[, (nm1):= lapply(.SD, `/`, 2), .SDcols=nm1]
```

Or a more efficient method with `data.table` for multiple columns would be using `set`.

```
for(j in nm1){
  set(df1, i=NULL, j=j, value=df1[[j]]/2)
}
```

#### data

```
 df1 <-  structure(list(Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Number1 = c(4L, 
 10L, 50L, 60L), Number2 = c(5L, 22L, 24L, 32L), Number3 = c(3L, 
 24L, 100L, 12L), Type = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L)), .Names = c("Letter", 
 "Number1", "Number2", "Number3", "Type"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Quick note that `mutate_each` is deprecated and now replaced by `mutate_all`, `mutate_at` or `mutate_if` . In this case, you would use `mutate_at` and you need to quote the helper function with `vars()`. The new correct dplyr code would be: `mutate_at(df1,  vars(starts_with('Number')), funs(./2))`

Answer (score 4):

A base `R` solution in case:

```
indx <- grepl("Number", names(df))
df[indx] <- df[indx]/2L

 #>df
 #    Letter Number1 Number2 Number3 Type
 #1      A       2     2.5     1.5   10
 #2      B       5    11.0    12.0   20
 #3      C      25    12.0    50.0   30
 #4      D      30    16.0     6.0   40
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
```

Create the test dataframe

```
letter <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
n1 <- c(4, 10, 50, 60)
n2 <- c(5, 22, 24, 32)
n3 <- c(3, 24, 100, 12)
type <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)

df <- data.frame(letter, n1, n2, n3, type)
```

The dataframe df:

```
# letter n1 n2  n3 type
# 1      A  4  5   3   10
# 2      B 10 22  24   20
# 3      C 50 24 100   30
# 4      D 60 32  12   40
```

Make your own function

```
mydivide <- function(x){x/2}
```

Use funs() to tell mutate what function to use.

Use the '-' to tell mutate not to mutate columns 'letter' and 'type'

```
df <- mutate_each(df, funs(mydivide), -letter, -type)
```

The end result:

```
# letter n1   n2   n3 type
# 1      A  2  2.5  1.5   10
# 2      B  5 11.0 12.0   20
# 3      C 25 12.0 50.0   30
# 4      D 30 16.0  6.0   40
```